# Declaring Spring Cloud Function definition property in multiple files

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

There are two business sub projects using Spring Cloud Function. They will be bundled to one Spring Boot Application. Is it possible to declare `spring.cloud.function.definition` property multiple times in different property files like below?

Project A:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: AProducer;AConsumer
    bindings:
      ...
```

Project B:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: BProducer;BConsumer
    bindings:
      ...
```

If it's not possible, how to handle such use case?

Comment: i have the same issue, looked for a solution everywhere but i couldn't found anything, please did you find any solution for this use case?